# Externalize hbm file out of Context - How to?

Tags: hibernate, spring

I'm trying to externalize the hbm files out of "Context". These hbm files are located in a directory called "test" just under tomcat home folder.
I have tried adding "test" to classpath and also too shared.loader or common.loader property of /conf/catalina.properties. It doesn't work.

Can someone help me to find the solution that am looking for?

Here is the piece of code from app-context.xml

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
        <value>com.test.model.Person</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:Person.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

EDIT:
The problem is, WebAppClassLoader look only in WEB-INF/classess. Is there a way to instruct the classloader to look at an external directory too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the external directory to classpath in setenv.bat and removed the "classpath" from classpath:Person.hbm.xml works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using property placeholders (`${jdbc.dialect}`), presumably you have a `<context:property-placeholder...>` somewhere in your configuration. One way is to specify the full path to the hbm.xml in whatever property-file you are loading there.

```
hibernate.config=/path/to/your/Person.hbm.xml
```

In your spring config

```
...
<property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>${hibernate.config}</value>
            </list>
</property>

...
```

EDIT: the path might have to be properly URL formatted, ie;

```
file:///d:/some/dir/Person.hbm.xml
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Please see my EDIT. Thanks for the reply.